# purchasing an item from my app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I have an IPhone app.And I would like to purchase items like clothes..... through app.So tell me which one is best way?

1.can I redirect to that website using webview ? or
2.Is there any other ways to purchase it?

If I redirect to that particular website then is it taking care of the transactions security?

Any  help is greatful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are purchasing an item from a web store through a windows application?  If so, the web view would be the way to go because it will handle the ssl hopefully implemented from the website, and it should be a breeze to implement.

If this does not answer your question, please reword it in a clear manner.

Comment: @sri be aware that an app that only has a UIWebView to show your website might be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Is the "store" you are purchasing from yours? while a UIWebView would do the trick just fine (using SSL of course), you would want to make sure the content is sized correctly for the iPhone's screen. IMHO, I would grab the raw data from the site and display it with native UI elements or else why just not visit the store in Mobile-Safari??

Answer (score 0):

you should just use apple inAppPurchase... it was born just for your purpose and works with the same iTune-iStore user account... and apple manage it...

Comment: If IAP was born for this why does apple write `Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected` in 11.3. of the App Store Review Guidelines?

Comment: @fluchtpunkt: you're right... i just guessed (but probably i was wrong, reading the original question again) that the "items like clothes" were virtual-clothes to be used INSIDE of the app for "avatars"...